# How to filter a list of a list of objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of Items and each item contains a list of components.

```
public class Item
{
    Item(string name)
    {
        ItemName = name;
    }
    public string ItemName { get; private set; }
    public List<Component> Components {get;set;}
}

public class Component
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Status {get;set;}
}

// Example
Item 1
    Component 1 - Status A
    Component 2 - Status B
    Component 3 - Status A
Item 2
    Component 1 - Status C
    Component 2 - Status C
    Component 3 - Status A
Item 3
    Component 1 - Status C
    Component 2 - Status C
    Component 3 - Status D
```

Using LINQ, how can I get only the components of all the items having their components with Status A or B?

The following solution is not what I am looking for:

```
var statuses = { "A" , "B" }
var result= items
                .Where(i => i.Components
                .Any(c => statuses.Contains(c.Status))
                .ToList();
```

This solution is returning the items with all the components in case that at least one component has the status A or B. In our example, items 1 and 2 will be returned with all their components. The result will be:

```
Item 1
    Component 1 - Status A
    Component 2 - Status B
    Component 3 - Status A
Item 2
    Component 1 - Status C
    Component 2 - Status C
    Component 3 - Status A
```

I will need a similar solution where the result will be:

```
Item 1
    Component 1 - Status A
    Component 2 - Status B
    Component 3 - Status A
Item 2
    Component 3 - Status A
```

Only components with Statuses A and B will be returned.

What is the correct syntax to achieve this task?

**EDIT:**

Per request, initialization of the items:

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item("Item 1")
    {
        Components = new List<Component>
        {
            new Component {Name ="Component1", Status = "A"},
            new Component {Name ="Component2", Status = "B"},
            new Component {Name ="Component3", Status = "A"}
         }
     },
     new Item("Item 2")
     {
         Components = new List<Component>
         {
            new Component {Name ="Component1", Status = "C"},
            new Component {Name ="Component2", Status = "C"},
            new Component {Name ="Component3", Status = "A"}
         }
     },
     new Item("Item 3")
     {
         Components = new List<Component>
         {
             new Component {Name ="Component1", Status = "C"},
             new Component {Name ="Component2", Status = "C"},
             new Component {Name ="Component3", Status = "D"}
          }
     }
};
```

Comment: If you could write a short C# sample showing the initialisation of your sample data, it would be quicker for us to write some solutions for you.

Comment: Change the `.Any(c => statuses.Contains(c.Status))` to `.All(c => statuses.Contains(c.Status))`. done

Comment: SelectMany will do the trick

Comment: Just to confirm. you want only the components or the items and their components that satisfy the predicate? It is not clear based on the wording of the question and the sample output shown. The two seem to conflict.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, yes this is what I need. The sample is what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible avenue to explore:

```
var statuses = new HashSet<string>() { "A", "B" };
var result = items
    .Where(i => i.Components.Any(c => statuses.Contains(c.Status)))
    .Select(z => new Item(z.ItemName) { Components = z.Components.Where(y => statuses.Contains(y.Status)).ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

*For this to work, you'll need to make the Item constructor public.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm just including this for completeness (and since I don't have enough reputation to comment). If you want just the components without the containing items, you can do it this way.

```
string[] statuses = { "A", "B" };
var things = items.SelectMany(x => x.Components.Where(y => statuses.Contains(y.Status)));

foreach (var thing in things)
    Console.WriteLine(thing);
```